# JavaScript what to change color by the use choise

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i start with javascript and want to make something..
i want the user will have a text area that he can write their what color he like (red, green, blue.....) press the button and the bg will change
i stack in the function area.. this is my code, id someone can tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#333333">
<form name="forme">
<p style="font-family:Tahome; font-size:20px; color:#06F">Please choose your favorite color background</p>
    <input type="text" name="color" onclick="color"() />
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="check()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function bgColor(color)
    {
    var chose="document.forme.color.value;
    document.bgColor = "color";     
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open your browser console you'll see lots of errors. For example, var chose="document.forme.color.value; is syntaxically invalid, same for onclick="color"(). I also suggest you read bases to achieve such thing, like http://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML and Javascript you can write:

```
<form>
    <input id="selected_color" type="text" placeholder="red,white,blue..." />
     <button  onclick="changeBg()">Change BgColor </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeBg(){

     //fetch the value from the input field
     var selected_color = document.getElementById('selected_color').value;

     //set the backgroundColor
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = selected_color;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a TextArea, but the following should give you an idea of how to do this.

HTML:

```
<form name="colorForm" id="colorForm">
    <select name="colorList"  id="colorList" />
    <input type="submit" value="Change Color" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Get Form Elements
var colorForm = document.getElementById('colorForm');
var colorList = document.getElementById('colorList');

// Colors
var colors = [
                {'key' : 'white', 'val': '#ffffff'},
                {'key' : 'black', 'val': '#000000'},
                {'key' : 'red',   'val': '#DC143C'},
                {'key' : 'green', 'val': '#006400'},
                {'key' : 'blue',  'val': '#0000FF'}
            ];

// Populate Select Element with colors
var len = colors.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // Create a new Option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = colors[i].key;
    opt.value = colors[i].val;
    // Add new Option to Select Element
    colorList.appendChild(opt);
}

// Bind Form's submit event
colorForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    // Stop form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get color from Select Element
    var color = colorList.options[colorList.selectedIndex].value;
    // Change color
    document.body.style.background = color;
});
```

Fiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/awff34kn/

Modify as needed.